# Create Merge Request via Gitlab CI without using Private Token

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are using Gitlab  8.16.5  and Gitlab API v3.
Build & Deployment are being done by Gitlab-CI. Build starts working on every push of feature and hotfix branches. There are 3 environments: Review, Staging & Production. Now We have made 2 manual actions on review deployment job: Review Accept & Review Reject. Simply, Review Environment is being setup for manual testing. That means in review accept, Manual testing passed & in review reject, manual test failed. 
Now, We have to create a MR on review accept job but do not want use any user's private token or private access token to create the same.

We have tried trigger token for the same but got {401: Unauthorised access}. Do triggers are only intended for rebuilding the job?

Answer (score 0):

The 'standard' workflow in Gitlab is a bit different : The idea would be that the developper creates a MR to submit his changes to review. And then a build is executed for this merge, the reviewer tests it and depending of the results of his tests, accepts or rejects the MR.
This way MR are always done by a user.

To sum it up it's not : Review/Test => Accept => Create MR
because after the merge you would need to test again.

So it is more : Create MR => Review/Test => Accept (or reject)

Comment: Thanks @CCH for the information. Is it any way to change the pipeline status based on manual action so that Merge request could not be accepted.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. You can have manual steps in your pipeline, but the MR does not live in the pipeline, so there is no standard way to update the MR status from within the pipeline, except for some hacks using the API as you apparently tried to do.